# html list in data-description attribute in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following code

**HTML**

```
<a class="caption" href="http://cargocollective.com/jaimemartinez/Illustration" data-title="Vulture" data-description="I felt compelled to walk on and find the place of these sounds, and when the forest did clear I was standing on a hill. Before me, there was a great plain. Upon it, the armies of the world, standing, waiting."><img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/PseudoElementsImageCaptions/images/3.jpg" alt="Illustration of Vulture"/></a>
```

I need to display HTML list (`<li>`) in data-description attribute of above tag.

Is it possible?

Comment: you can't display an element in an attribute of another element. Maybe you mean you want to store html of a list in the data description?

Comment: yes, I want to store html of a list in the data description

Answer (score 3):

In short, no. You can't include plain HTML within data- attribute values as it's invalid markup.

If you're parsing the attributes to do other things with, you might consider using something like Markdown which you can then convert to DOM elements later on.

Comment: is it possible to set HTML using css attribute 'content'? .caption::before {
 content: attr(data-description);